# How to add a parent event handler from inside an inherited widget plugin using jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui

I am extending a jQuery UI widget using the $.widget factory.  In this particular case I'm inheriting from Wijmo's wijlinechart.  I need to respond to the wijlinechart's "painted" event from within my child class.

Consider this:

```
         $.widget("bw.wijlinechartcursor", $.wijmo.wijlinechart, {
             _create: function () {
                 var self = this;
                 $.wijmo.wijlinechart.prototype._create.apply(self, arguments);

                 self.element.on("painted", function (e) {
                     alert("Got painted in child via element.on"); // Doesn't get called.
                 });

                 // This works, but blows away the client code's handler (below)
                 self.options.painted = function (e) {
                    alert("Got painted in child class via options.painted!");
                 }                   

             },

             _painted: function () {
                 alert("Got painted in child via _painted");  // Doesn't get called.
             }
         });

         $("#mywijlinechartcursor").wijlinechartcursor({
             // ... stuff...
             painted: function (e) {
                 alert("Got painted in client code");
             }
         });
```

So what is the most effective way to handle an event down in a child class that is _trigger'ed by an inherited parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding to the event with `on()` should work, then again that event is probably not named `painted`.

Each widget has its own event prefix, which defaults to the widget's name. If your base widget is not overriding this default value, the event will be named `wijlinechartpainted`.

In any case, the prefix is available in the widget's `widgetEventPrefix` property, so you can write:

```
self.element.on(self.widgetEventPrefix + "painted", function(e) {
    alert("Got painted in child via element.on");  // Should be called.
});
```

Comment: **That did the trick!**  Thanks so much -- I just wasn't connecting the dots there with the event prefix.  Got it now!

Comment: It is surprising, but 'self.widgetEventPrefix' should be lowercased before building event name, because _trigger() makes event name **lowercase** (jQuery UI v.1.8.20):
`self.element.on(self.widgetEventPrefix.toLowerCase() + "painted", function(){});`

If I knew this earlier, I would save few hours of debugging through jQuery...